# How to slow a foreach for a few seconds in android?

Tags: android

I have a loop with a call to server, but until the call to server comes back the loop continue to next item
How to slow the loop until the call to server comes back?

```
for (UserQuickBlox item : QBuser) {
createDialog(item); //A function that accesses the QuickBlox server and create Chat , until the call to server comes back, it continues to the next item.
 }
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please share some code or some more details about what you've tried so far.

Comment: "How to suspend foreach" is the wrong question to ask. I think you need to study asynchronous programming first.

Comment: You _can_ use Java's `Future` [(documentation here)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to make the current thread wait until an operation in a `FutureTask` is completed. Whether that's a good or a very very horrible idea depends on your application architecture. It shouldn't be used to block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `createDialog` call launches the server communication that takes some time to complete, what you want to do is not **delay each pass of the loop** but rather **wait until each server call finishes** before calling the next one.

To do this take a look at [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#asynctask)